# Preferred way to detect two-way binging change in Angular 1.6?

Tags: angularjs

I'm looking for preferred way to detect a change of two-way binding.

- `$onChanges` works with `<` and `@` bindings.
- `$doCheck` brings a lot of extra checks that I need to do, especially when there are more than 1 digest cycles.

So what would be a more native way to detect a change on two-way binding:

```
bindings: {
    prop: '='
}
```

Comment: how about `$scope.$watch` and/or `$scope.$watchCollection`?

Comment: do you mean something like `$scope.$watch(function () { return ... });` ?

Comment: something like `$scope.$watch('prop', function(newVal, OldVal){ /*do stuff */};`

Comment: well, since property is bound to controller, not the scope, the watch by property name won't work. But I got the idea. The problem with that there's too much manual work too, same as with `$doCheck`. But looks like these are the only ways.

Comment: i'm not sure what you mean by "bound to the controller". the syntax you used in your original question looks like angular2. in angular1.x you'd do a two way binding in a directive with an isolate scope. in angular2 you use `bindings` in a component. so are you using angular 1.x or angular 2?

Comment: @chukkwagon you can use `bindings` in component angularJs as well